# How to inflate an object of type Fragment in a view?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, android-inflate

I'm trying to save the state of a fragment so that it doesn't have to reload everything when i come back to it.
I have a fragment in which i saved his state. I'm getting it this way:

```
Fragment f = getFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "mContent");
```

Now i want it to be inflated in the view. It seems from the documentation that I can only do it using something like this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
```

That's not ok because it recreates the fragment from scratch. I want, instead, to be "Fragment f" to be inflated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a fragment to the fragmentmanager and show/hide it to keep it's state.
Ofcourse it recreates the fragment from scratch if you're using only the layout xml file.
Try to pass the fragment object instead of the layout file

Comment: Also why do you need a fragment in a view? you can use a framelayout to place fragments in...